# Zip `Observable` and `Flowable`

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `Flowable` and a `Observable`.

I want to `zip` them as one `Observable`.

But the `Flowable` should be `request` only when `Observable`'s value comes.

Can I do this operation by plug-in operators?

Comment: Why do you need this complicated interaction? If requesting just when the observable produces is a mandatory requirement, you'll need a custom operator.

Comment: Hi @akarnokd. My case is there is a UI event `Observable` and and a IO releated `Flowable`. When UI event comes, I need to `request` the content. The `Flowable` upstream is from other API and the downstream will use the coming value to update the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Does that fit your requirement?

```
getObservable()
        .flatMap(valueFromObservable -> getFlowable().toObservable())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: That will create and subscribe a new `Flowable` once a new value comes from `Observable`.